# Debian 10 apt update suddenly stopped working without config change: Unknown error executing apt-key

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude

I am having a problem with apt update on Debian Buster which suddenly stopped working a few days ago. I have compared the /etc/apt directory with the backup and there seem to be no changes whatsoever.

On another Debian Buster system, the same key in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d with the same MD5 checksum works perfectly:

```
root@domac:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d# md5sum debian-archive-buster-stable.gpg
4797ff6df738da65413ef710cf73936f  debian-archive-buster-stable.gpg
root@domac:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d#
```

The output of apt-get update is:

```
root@domac:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d# apt-get update
Get:1 http://ftp.carnet.hr/carnet-debian carnet-buster InRelease [4,719 B]
Get:2 http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.srce.hr/srce-debian srce-buster InRelease [6,723 B]
Get:4 http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]
Get:5 http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease [46.7 kB]
Get:6 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease [6,837 B]
Err:1 http://ftp.carnet.hr/carnet-debian carnet-buster InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Get:7 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Err:3 http://ftp.srce.hr/srce-debian srce-buster InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Get:8 http://repo.vulners.com/debian buster InRelease [10.3 kB]
Err:2 http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:4 http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:5 http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:6 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:7 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:8 http://repo.vulners.com/debian buster InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Get:9 https://repo.cloudlinux.com/kernelcare-debian/10 stable InRelease [3,302 B]
Err:9 https://repo.cloudlinux.com/kernelcare-debian/10 stable InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ftp.carnet.hr/carnet-debian carnet-buster InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://ftp.carnet.hr/carnet-debian carnet-buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.srce.hr/srce-debian srce-buster InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://ftp.srce.hr/srce-debian srce-buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://ftp.hr.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://repo.vulners.com/debian buster InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://repo.vulners.com/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://repo.cloudlinux.com/kernelcare-debian/10 stable InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'https://repo.cloudlinux.com/kernelcare-debian/10 stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@domac:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d#
```

I have tried:

```
# cd /var/lib/apt
# mv lists lists.old
# mdkir -p lists/partial lists/auxfiles
# chmod 755 lists lists/auxfiles
# chmod 700 lists/partial
```

I have also tried `apt -oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 update`, but it is illegible.

apt-key list seems the same like the system where apt update works:

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   dsa1024 2007-10-30 [SC]
      0E11 83A6 46FC 9255 D1B1  9664 53FB D252 EC72 006A
uid           [ unknown] CARNet Paketi <paketi@CARNet.hr>
sub   elg2048 2007-10-30 [E]

pub   dsa1024 2007-11-06 [SC]
      E2FF F795 7AEC 9D51 18B9  5BE2 FECB 4210 4089 CBA3
uid           [ unknown] Srce paketi <paketi@srce.hr>
sub   elg2048 2007-11-06 [E]

pub   rsa2048 2014-02-10 [SC]
      0343 27E8 2064 69CB 296A  C14E CCE8 0D2B 8B53 D14B
uid           [ unknown] KernelCare <info@kernelcare.com>
sub   rsa2048 2014-02-10 [E]

pub   dsa1024 2014-06-23 [SC]
      E58F E9B3 FE3B 0470 5251  59BD 6DC3 D600 CDEF 74BB
uid           [ unknown] KernelCare <security@kernelcare.com>
sub   elg2048 2014-06-23 [E]

pub   rsa3072 2019-03-18 [SC] [expires: 2024-02-16]
      1505 8500 A023 5D97 F5D1  0063 B188 E2B6 95BD 4743
uid           [ unknown] DEB.SURY.ORG Automatic Signing Key <deb@sury.org>
sub   rsa3072 2019-03-18 [E] [expires: 2024-02-16]

pub   rsa4096 2021-02-18 [SC]
      3DC5 64C8 48D9 C7C3 1507  2953 6AED 0D64 4132 004C
uid           [ unknown] KernelCare <security@kernelcare.com>

pub   rsa2048 2017-05-03 [SC]
      C69B C10E 6F34 FE17 326C  D3F2 0696 3113 8D04 4866
uid           [ unknown] vulners.com <admin@vulners.com>
sub   rsa2048 2017-05-03 [E]

pub   rsa2048 2011-08-19 [SC] [expires: 2024-06-14]
      573B FD6B 3D8F BC64 1079  A6AB ABF5 BD82 7BD9 BF62
uid           [ unknown] nginx signing key <signing-key@nginx.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-bullseye-automatic.gpg
------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [SC] [expires: 2029-01-15]
      1F89 983E 0081 FDE0 18F3  CC96 73A4 F27B 8DD4 7936
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (11/bullseye) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [S] [expires: 2029-01-15]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-bullseye-security-automatic.gpg
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [SC] [expires: 2029-01-15]
      AC53 0D52 0F2F 3269 F5E9  8313 A484 4904 4AAD 5C5D
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (11/bullseye) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2021-01-17 [S] [expires: 2029-01-15]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-bullseye-stable.gpg
---------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2021-02-13 [SC] [expires: 2029-02-11]
      A428 5295 FC7B 1A81 6000  62A9 605C 66F0 0D6C 9793
uid           [ unknown] Debian Stable Release Key (11/bullseye) <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-automatic.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2019-04-14 [SC] [expires: 2027-04-12]
      80D1 5823 B7FD 1561 F9F7  BCDD DC30 D7C2 3CBB ABEE
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (10/buster) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2019-04-14 [S] [expires: 2027-04-12]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-security-automatic.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2019-04-14 [SC] [expires: 2027-04-12]
      5E61 B217 265D A980 7A23  C5FF 4DFA B270 CAA9 6DFA
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (10/buster) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2019-04-14 [S] [expires: 2027-04-12]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-stable.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2019-02-05 [SC] [expires: 2027-02-03]
      6D33 866E DD8F FA41 C014  3AED DCC9 EFBF 77E1 1517
uid           [ unknown] Debian Stable Release Key (10/buster) <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

[snip]
```

I ran out of ideas about what might have gone wrong ... Thank you.

P.S.

Here is the requested output of the `apt -oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 update` command. It was too huge for copy + paste, so I put it on this link: [apt-get update debug output](https://domac.alu.hr/mtodorov/apt-get-debug--2021-11-01.txt)

Comment: Can you provide the output of apt -oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 update please?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently,

```
# rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# apt update
```

is sufficient, as shown here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/131601/gpg-error-release-the-following-signatures-were-invalid-badsig, but it takes some time for unknown reasons.

At first, a few `apt update` commands have generated more errors, but then the apt system recovered after some time without further modification to /var/lib/apt or settings (or keys, keys were the same as on the twin system that did not break as I think I mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

For me, on Debian Bookworm (which deprecated `apt-key add`) it was file permissions. I.e. I had in my `sources.list`:

```
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/dnsdist-18-pub.asc arch=amd64] http://repo.powerdns.com/debian bookworm-dnsdist-18 main
```

and had appropriate `/etc/apt/keyrings/dnsdist-18-pub.asc` owned by root with permission `0600` (due to `umask 0077` before I did `wget(1)`/`curl(1)` of that file)

Although `apt(8)` is run as root, it drops its user permissions to `_apt` in newer Debian releases by default, so it could not read that file, which resulted in those errors:

```
# apt update
Get:1 http://repo.powerdns.com/debian bookworm-dnsdist-18 InRelease [1801 B]
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Err:1 http://repo.powerdns.com/debian bookworm-dnsdist-18 InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Hit:3 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:4 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Get:5 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports InRelease [56.5 kB]

[...]

Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repo.powerdns.com/debian bookworm-dnsdist-18 InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://repo.powerdns.com/debian bookworm-dnsdist-18 InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

I've tried to debug it with `apt -oDebug::Acquire::gpgv=1 update` (see `DEBUG` section in `apt.conf(5)`) which indicated it was not even considering specified `/etc/apt/keyrings/dnsdist-18-pub.asc`.

---

In the end, simple `chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/dnsdist-18-pub.asc` was all that was needed to fix that obscure error.